# Continuous map between $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

The following theorem appears in Appendix B of Rabinowitz' book Minimax Methods in Critical Point Theory:

Let $\Omega \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ be bounded and $g\in C(\overline{\Omega}\times \Bbb {R},\Bbb {R})$ such that there exist constants $r,s\ge 1$ and $a_1,a_2\ge 0$ such that for all $x \in \overline{\Omega}, y\in \Bbb{R}$ $$|g(x,y)|\le a_1 + a_2|y|^{r/s}$$
Then the map $\varphi(x)\mapsto g(x,\varphi(x))$ belongs to $C(L^r(\Omega),L^s(\Omega))$.

In the proof, he says "To prove the continuity of this map, observe that it is continuous at $\varphi$  if and only if $f(x,z(x)) = g(x,z(x)+\varphi(x))-g(x,\varphi(x))$ is continuous at $z=0$. Therefore we can assume $\varphi = 0$ and $g(x,0)=0$."

I don't understand how this assumpion can be made without loss of generality, and was unable to finish the proof without it. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I have found a partial answer in a different thread:
[Continuity proof of a function between $L^p$ spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2843090/continuity-proof-of-a-function-between-lp-spaces?rq=1)

In the post it says:
Using the growth estimate, one can derive a similar estimate for $f$ of the form: 
$$
|f(x,z(x))|\leq A_1+A_2 |\phi_0(x)|^{r/p}+A_3|z(x)|^{r/p}
$$

This would solve my problem, since the former two constants don't depend on $z$ and can be thrown together, leaving the case that was already proven. However, I couldn't derive this estimate.

edit2: I was wrong in assuming this solves the problem since, as pointed out by the users supinf and Peter Melech, the constant may not depend on x.

Answer (score 4):

For $x\in\overline{\Omega}$ and $\frac{r}{s}\geq 1$ You get
$$|f(x,z(x))|=|g(x,z(x)+\varphi(x))-g(x,\phi(x))|\leq a_1+a_2|z(x)+\varphi|^{\frac{r}{s}}+a_1+a_2|\varphi(x)|^{\frac{r}{s}}\leq$$
$$2a_1+a_22^{\frac{r}{s}-1}(|z(x)|^{\frac{r}{s}}+|\varphi(x)|^{\frac{r}{s}})+a_2|\varphi(x)|^{\frac{r}{s}}\leq $$
$$\underbrace{2a_1}_{=A_1}+\underbrace{(a_22^{\frac{r}{s}-1}+a_2)}_{=A_2}|\varphi(x)|^{\frac{r}{s}}+\underbrace{a_22^{\frac{r}{s}-1}}_{=A_3}|z(x)|^\frac{r}{s}$$
where You used that $(\frac{a+b}{2})^{\frac{r}{s}}\leq\frac{a^\frac{r}{s}+b^\frac{r}{s}}{2}$ which holds by the convexity of $x\mapsto x^{\frac{r}{s}}$ and Jensen's inequality. In the case $\frac{r}{s}<1$ You can proceed analogously using $(a+b)^{\frac{r}{s}}\leq a^{\frac{r}{s}}+b^{\frac{r}{s}}$ valid in this range.

Comment: How would this help? You still have dependence on $x$ in the inequality for $f$, whereas you dont have dependence on $x$ in the assumption for $g$.

Comment: Yes, I think so too and this is just an answer to the OP's question concerning the derivation of this estimate. To proceed further one has to argue via dominated convergence as in the question quoted by the OP and " Therefor we can assume $\varphi=0$... in Rabinowitz's book seems to be not correct or at least quite sloppy

Comment: You are correct, this alone doesn't solve the problem.